# Python vectorization with a constant

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have a series X of length n(=300,000). Using a window length of w (=40), I need to implement:

mu(i)= X(i)-X(i-w)

s(i) = sum{k=i-w to i} [X(k)-X(k-1) - mu(i)]^2

I was wondering if there's a way to prevent loops here. The fact that mu(i) is constant in second equation is causing complications in vectorization. I did the following so far:

```
x1=x.shift(1)
xw=x.shift(w)
mu= x-xw 
dx=(x-x1-mu)**2 # wrong because mu wouldn't be constant for each i
s=pd.rolling_sum(dx,w)
```

The above code would work (and was working) in a loop setting but takes too long, so any help regarding vectorization or other speed improvement methods would be helpful. I posted this on crossvalidated with mathjax formatting but that doesn't seem to work here.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241050/python-vectorization-with-a-constant

Also just to clarify, I wasn't using a double loop, just a single one originally:

```
        for i in np.arange(w, len(X)):
            x=X.ix[i-w:i,0] # clip a series of size w
            x1=x.shift(1)   
            mu.ix[i]= x.ix[-1]-x.ix[0]   
            temp= (x-x1-mu.ix[i])**2   # returns a series of size w but now mu is constant
            s.ix[i]= temp.sum()
```

Comment: Since you seem to have two variables to loop over, could you do something with 2D arrays, specifying the axis where necessary. Not sure how pandas' `rolling_sum` would behave with that, but alternatively, it looks like you could do all the work in your equations with numpy alone on 2D arrays.

Comment: Still half asleep, so I might be wrong. I'd say you can expand the square as the addition of three factors. The first one is a convolution (squared), that you can do very quickly using np.convolve, the second one is mu**2, which you have already, and the third one is the convolution above multiplied bu mu...

Comment: In any case, in my opinion the first thing to avoid costly loops in array multiplication/summation is through convolutions!

Comment: Thanks @Evert for 2 D suggestion, the answer by Divakar below presents one such approach.

Comment: @Jblasco, thanks for mentioning convolutions and the suggestion of expansion. Together they help prevent a loop

Comment: Very welcome, @dayum. I'm just sorry I didn't have the time to write it out properly as an answer. If you feel what you did is the best possible thing, I believe it is traditional to write it as an answer and accept it, so that next person sees the best possible answer accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** One vectorized approach would be using [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
N = X.shape[0]
a = np.arange(N)
k2D = a[:,None] - np.arange(w+1)[::-1]
mu1D = X - X[a-w]
out = ((X[k2D] - X[k2D-1] - mu1D[:,None])**2).sum(-1)
```

We can further optimize the last step to get squared summations with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
subs = X[k2D] - X[k2D-1] - mu1D[:,None]
out = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',subs,subs)
```

Further improvement is possible with the use of [`NumPy strides`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html) to get `X[k2D]` and `X[k2D-1]`.

---

**Approach #2 :** To save on memory when working very large arrays, we can use one loop instead of two loops used in the original code, like so -

```
N = X.shape[0]
s = np.zeros((N))
k_idx = np.arange(-w,1)
for i in range(N):
    mu = X[i]-X[i-w]
    s[i] = ((X[k_idx]-X[k_idx-1] - mu)**2).sum()
    k_idx += 1
```

Again, `np.einsum` could be used here to compute `s[i]`, like so -

```
subs = X[k_idx]-X[k_idx-1] - mu
s[i] = np.einsum('i,i->',subs,subs)
```

Comment: Thanks, i was using your Approach #2 originally but the loop takes very long. Approach #1 using 2D arrays looks promising but I need to work on understanding it better. I applied it blindly and got a `raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])` on the `out=...` line

Comment: @dayum I assumed `X` as a NumPy array, so I guess we need to do that conversion that up-front. Are you doing that?

Comment: OK so now out is a 2D array also of shape (N,w+1). In my case, "s" would be a 1D array of shape(N)

Comment: @dayum So, the question stated : `"X of length n(=300,000)"`. So, I assumed that would be a `1D array`. What's the shape of `X`?

Comment: It is 1D -  >>> X.shape...Out[1]: (340486L, 1L)

Comment: @dayum That's 2D. So, do : `X_arr = X.ravel().` See if the shape is `(340486L,)`, which represents `1D` and if it's so, then go ahead and try out the approaches.

Comment: Ok, that worked. All that's left to do now is to understand what's going on behind the scenes! Thanks for the help Divakar.

Comment: hi @Divakar, in your solution above `a[:,None]`  is of shape (N,1) while `np.arange(w+1)[::-1]` is of shape (w,) . Now when you do `a[:,None] - np.arange(w+1)[::-1]`, how is the resulting shape (N,w)?

Comment: never mind, your reference on broadcasting is helpful ....I cant delete the above comment